# What does this line mean obj.sayColor=sayColor

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    window.color='red';
    var obj={ color: 'blue'}

    function sayColor(){
        document.writeln(this.color);
    }

    sayColor();
    obj.sayColor=sayColor;
    obj.sayColor();
</script>
```

What does this line `obj.sayColor=sayColor` mean? Is it assigning the function to the object?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it is - I assume it is to show the scope of `this` when you call  `sayColor()` (which is actually `window.sayColor()`) vs `obj.sayColor()`

Comment: So the first call of the function will write red as the local scope is window and `window.color` is red. the second call `obj.sayColor()` will write blue as the function was passed by reference  and attached to the obj. This is a good way to understand isolated scopes :D

Answer (score 1):

When you call `sayColor` the first time, `this` in the function is referencing the `window` object, so it will write `red` out to the document.

By assigning it to `obj` the function will now use `obj` as `this`, so `this.color` is `blue`.

```js
window.color = 'red';
var obj = {
  color: 'blue'
}

function sayColor() {
  console.log(this.color);
}

sayColor(); // this = window
obj.sayColor = sayColor;
obj.sayColor(); // this = obj
```

The scope of `sayColor()` is window, because every object in JS has some root element, in the Browser, that's the window. So instead of  just `sayColor()` you could also write `window.sayColor()`:

```js
window.color = 'red';

function sayColor() {
  console.log(this.color);
}

window.sayColor(); // this = window
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you are calling the function `sayColor();`, it will execute the line of code `document.writeln(this.color);` which will display the color value which is assigned to the `color` property of the `window` since `this` refers to `window` here.

But when you do

```
obj.sayColor=sayColor;
obj.sayColor();
```

It assigns the function `sayColor()` to `sayColor` property of `obj`. And since `sayColor()` is a function the object treats this as a method(not property). Now, when the code `obj.sayColor();` is executed the line of code `document.writeln(this.color);` executes where `this` has a scope of `obj`. So, it displays the color value of `obj` property.

```js
window.color='red';
var obj={ color: 'blue'}

function sayColor(){
  document.writeln(this.color);
}

//this.color where this has scope of window
sayColor();
obj.sayColor=sayColor;
//this.color where this has scope of obj
obj.sayColor();
```

Answer (score 0):

obj.sayColor can be anything like string,number,function etc..

say,
obj.sayColor ="your name";

now its a normal string ,
If you call it now like obj.sayColor it will print "your name".

If you set obj.SetColor as a function,when u call the function it will be called.

because function sayColor is already defined.

obj.sayColor is creating a new property to the object obj and setting function sayColor as its reference.

Now when you call obj.sayColor() it will call the function sayColor which is already mapped to the object obj